# PCA sklearn - Which dimension does it take

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, pca

Does sklearn PCA consider the columns of the dataframe as the vectors to reduce or  the rows as vectors to reduce ?

Because when doing this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,-21,45,3,4],[4,5,89,-5,6],[7,-4,58,1,19]‌​,[10,11,74,20,12],[1‌​3,14,15,45,78]]) #5 rows 5 columns
pca=PCA(n_components=3)
pca.fit(df)
df_pcs=pd.DataFrame(data=pca.components_, index = df.index)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 3), indices imply (5, 5)

Answer (score 3):

Rows represent samples and columns represent features. [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA) reduces the dimensionality of the data, ie features. So columns.

So if you are talking about vectors, then it considers a row as single feature vector and reduces its size.

If you have a dataframe of shape say `[100, 6]` and PCA `n_components` is set to 3. So your output will be `[100, 3]`.

```
# You need this
df_pcs=pca.transform(df)

# This produces error because shapes dont match.
df_pcs=pd.DataFrame(data=pca.components_, index = df.index)
```

`pca.components_` is an array of [3,5] and your `index` parameter is using the `df.index` which is of shape `[5,]`. Hence the error. `pca.components_` represents a completely different thing.

According to documentation:-

> components_ : array, [n_components, n_features]
>
> ```
> Principal axes in feature space, representing the 
> directions of maximum variance in the data.
> ```

Comment: Thank you. But in this case why does the following fail ?
`df=pd.DataFrame([[1,-21,45,3,4],[4,5,89,-5,6],[7,-4,58,1,19],[10,11,74,20,12],[13,14,15,45,78]]) #5 rows 5 columns  pca=PCA(n_components=3) pca.fit(df) df_pcs=pd.DataFrame(data=pca.components_, index = df.index)
`

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? Please explain and if required edit the question to add the stack trace of error. Add the code you used to initialize the PCA.

Comment: You need to use `pca.transform()` to get the new dataset. You are currently using `components_` which represents the directions of features in new dimension space, not the actual reduced feature vectors if that what you are thinking.

Comment: I am not sure to get it. The aim of the PCA is to reduce my 5 vectors to 3 Principal Components. So I should take the `components_` right ? Or maybe the `components_` are not the PCs and in this case the name is very misleading?